# JavaScript Regex Replace Last Underscore and Digits Before File Extension

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I get rid of the last underscore and digits that follow it in my file names.

Here is an example:

Case #1

```
fileName_01.jpg --> fileName.jpg
```

Case #1

```
file_Name_01.jpg --> file_Name.jpg
```

Case #3

```
file_Name_.jpg --> file_Name_.jpg
```

jsfiddle test file: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2t3rR/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function RegexTester() {
            debugger;
            var string = 'fileName_01.jpg';
            var regex = new RegExp('_[0-9]+\.');
            string = string.replace(regex, '.'); //Result - fileName.jpg

            string = 'file_Name_01.jpg';
            string = string.replace(regex, '.'); //Result - file_Name.jpg

            string = 'file_Name_.jpg';
            string = string.replace(regex, '.'); //Result - file_Name_.jpg
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: you just rehashed the other answers ¬¬

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use a lookahead and don't match the dot:

```
"file_name_01.jpg".replace(/_\d+(?=\.)/, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

How will be this?

```
"fileName_01.jpg".replace(/_\d+(\.[^.]+)$/,"$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern `/_[0-9]+\./` and replace with `.`

```
strArr[i].replace(/_[0-9]+\./, ".")
```

The trailing `.` is a weak attempt to make sure that we only replace numbers preceding the extension so we don't turn "file_01_name.jpg" into "file_name.jpg".

This will fail on things like "file_01.asdf.jpg" where it will convert to "file.asdf.jpg", but this sort of file name hopefully doesn't occur in your application. (Otherwise we'd have to make a regex and hard-code in the file extensions).